# Signing certificate not found: CN=********.server.domain.com in Thinktecture

Tags: .net, iis, certificate, single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server

We have thinktecture identity server implemented in one of our project.
I have seen the KeyMaterialConfiguration table in IdentityServerConfigurations database is having "SigningCertificate".
I have created similar certificate in IIS of the same machine (where IdentityServer is deployed) by creating it as a "Self-Signed Certificate" with the same name.

Still when I run - `http://localhost/identityserver`, it gives an error saying "Signing Certificate not found.."

Could anyone please guide to resolve this error?

Its just eating up a lot of time of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your certificate is installed in your web host certificate repository under "Local Computer\Personal\" and that the user running the website application pool has read access to the certificate private key.
In the certificate management console, after importing the certificate to "Local Computer\Personal\", right click the certificate choose "All tasks" -> "Manage Private Keys" and add read access to the user running the website application pool.